# Save File to Sharepoint Server using JAX-WS

Tags: java, sharepoint, jax-ws

I'm trying to save a file to a Sharepoint server using JAX-WS. The web service call is reporting a success, but the file doesn't show up.

I used this command (from a WinXP) to generate the Java code to make the JAX-WS call:

```
wsimport -keep -extension -Xnocompile http://hostname/sites/teamname/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx?WSDL
```

I get a handle on the web service which I called `port` using the following:
CopySoap port = null;

```
if (userName != null && password != null) {
    Copy service = new Copy();
    port = service.getCopySoap();
    ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, userName);
    ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
} else {
    throw new Exception("Holy Frijolé! Null userName and/or password!");
}
```

I called the web service using the following:

```
port.copyIntoItems(sourceUrl, destUrlCollection, fields ,
    "Contents of the file".getBytes(), 
    copyIntoItemsResult, copyResultCollection)
```

The `sourceUrl` and the only url in `destUrlCollection` equals "hostname/sites/teamname/Tech Docs/Sub Folder".

The `FieldInformationCollection` object named `fields` contains only one `FieldInformation`. 
The `FieldInformation` object has "HelloWorld.txt" as the value for displayName, internalName and value.
The type property is set to `FieldType.FILE`. The id property is set to `(java.util.UUID.randomUUID()).toString()`.

The call to `copyIntoItems` returns successfuly; `copyIntoItemsResult` contains a value of 0 and the only `CopyResult` object
set in `copyResultCollection` has an error code of "SUCCESS" with a null error message.

When I look into the "Tech Docs" library on Sharepoint, in the "Sub Folder" there's no file there.

Why wouldn't it tell me what I did wrong? Did I just miss a step?

**Update (Feb 26th, 2011)**

I've changed my FieldInformation object's displayName and internalName properties to be "Title" as suggested. Still no joy, but a step in the right direction.

After playing around with the urls for a bit, I got these results:

With both the sourceUrl and the only destination URL equivalent, with no protocol, I get the SUCCESS response but no actual document appears in the document library.

With both of the URLs equivalent but with an "http://" protocol specified, I get an UNKNOWN error with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." as the message.

With the source URL an empty string or `null`, I get an UNKNOWN error with " Value does not fall within the expected range." as the error message.

**Update (March 2nd, 2011)**

As suggested by Alexei Levenkov, I used Fiddler to see what was going on and found this:

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
34  401 HTTP    hostname    /sites/teamname/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx?WSDL 1,656       text/html   javaw:5304          
35  401 HTTP    hostname    /sites/teamname/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx?WSDL 1,539       text/html   javaw:5304          
36  200 HTTP    hostname    /sites/teamname/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx?WSDL 10,887  private     text/xml; charset=utf-8 javaw:5304          
37  401 HTTP    hostname    /sites/teamname/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx  1,656       text/html   javaw:5304          
38  401 HTTP    hostname    /sites/teamname/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx  1,539       text/html   javaw:5304          
39  200 HTTP    hostname    /sites/teamname/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx  611 private, max-age=0      text/xml; charset=utf-8 javaw:5304
```

It looks like a simple handshake going on until it gets the HTTP 200 for both the WSDL and the web service call.

So I tried not putting my username and password in the RequestContext and I get a similar thing as I do above for the WSDL request (two HTTP 401s and one HTTP 200), but the WebService call only has one HTTP 200. If it no longer uses my username/password, then it should theoretically fail authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Destination Urls should contain full paths to files. I check out sample on method description page - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy.copy.copyintoitems.aspx.

Comment: When I use full paths for both source and destnation (i.e. include the http:// part)I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." as an error message. When I use full path for just the destination only and leave source as empty string, I get "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Comment: Worked for me (C#... but as long as you manage to call WS it should not matter what language you use) with: fileName for source, absolute Url (with file part) for destination, empty field collection. Try to collect Fiddler (or other HTTP watcher) trace and see if there is something suspicious. You can also see trace while using SharePoint's Copy to functionality to compare to yours.

Comment: Basically, my Java installation was sending in my machines' username/password instead of the one I was setting. I don't know how to force it to send the username/password I want. Sorry for the delay in accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is probably the fields.

DisplayName and InternalName want to be "Title", and the value be HelloWorld.txt

Also, leave ID empty, SharePoint will populate that.

Comment: I tried that, but no luck. Could it be that the source and destination URLs don't have an http:// or https:// in front of them?

Comment: Perhaps. If you're  uploading a file from somewhere that's not sharepoint, I think the source URL can be null, or at least an emptyy string.

Answer (score 0):

Check SharePoint logs in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\LOGS. Maybe missing domain part in username is causing problems?

Comment: I guess I can't avoid the sharepoint admins anymore. I did notice that the "Auth" reported by Fiddler reported the user and domain I log into my development machine with, not the username I use for Sharepoint which does seem odd since I use my Sharepoint credentials in my Java code.